# at the expense of

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have some problem with "at the cost of" here. Does

***"light reveals itself at the expense of obscuring something else"***

mean:

1. light reveals itself by lighting other things (because light itself has no physical presence and so is defined with its effects)?

or

2. light reveals itself by obscuring other things?

Comment: The latter; "at the expense of" is a mostly fixed phrase which introduces the cost of the foregoing or something previously discussed. In other words, "the trade-off is..."

Answer (score 1):

The second meaning is the correct one in this case. Your phrase could be translated along the lines of: `Something else is obscured because the light reveals itself.`